# How to get matched text from a given list which is given to fuzzy wuzzy partial_ratio()?

Tags: python, nlp, fuzzywuzzy

I have a string and a list of strings.
I just want to know which text in the list is 100% partially matched with the given string.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz 

s1 = "Hello"
s_list= ["Hai all", "Hello world", "Thank you"]

fuzz.partial_ratio(s1, s_list)
```

For this am getting 100. Since "Hello" has a partial match with  "Hello world"
But how can I get "Hello World" as output?

Could anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need fuzzywuzzy for exact matching. Fuzzywuzzy is for fuzzy matching. Fuzzywuzzy cannot produce indexes for matches precisely because, in general, there is no "match", just distances.

All you need is Python.

```
s1 = "Hello"
s_list= ["Hai all", "Hello world", "Thank you"]

for item in s_list:
    if s1 in item:
        print("item: " + item + "\ns1" + s1)
```

Comment: Thank you @Neil.
This answer fits perfectly with my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different function

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import process

s1 = "Hello"
s_list= ["Hai all", "Hello world", "Thank you"]

[s for s, m in process.extract(s1, s_list) if m == 100]
```

For more info check `help(process.extract)`.
If you strictly want the 100% partial matches, Neil's answer is better.

Comment: This is drastically more expensive than using "in".

Comment: This also will only return "Hello world" even if there is another match, eg "Hello there" in the list as well.

Comment: @Neil I assumed that OP wanted to use this library, though I can see it's not his priority.

Comment: Thank you @kuco23 and Neil for your answers.

My intention is to get a 100% partial match, since am tried fuzzy-wuzzy I posted and stuck there I posted in that manner.
But Neil's answer suits better for my requirement. Thank you Neil. :)